# wget: where does it look for certificates?

Tags: ssl, openssl, wget

I have a HTTPS-site that needs an intermediate-certificate to verify the servers SSL-certificate.

If I put the intermediate-cert into /etc/ssl/certs (and make the hash-link) then

```
openssl s_client -connect IP:PORT
```

will work. Otherwise I get a verification error.

Where does wget look for certificates? I only can make it work if I explicitly set --ca-directory in wget.

So it seems openssl looks into /etc/ssl/certs and wget does not.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

If I run wget with -d then I see without --ca-directory it loads 
about 150 certificates. With the option it is over 300. So it must be another path then openssl-default I think.

Wget 1.19.4 on linux-gnu on Debian 10

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to https://serverfault.com

Comment: check https://serverfault.com/questions/373920/ubuntu-11-10-using-wget-curl-fails-with-ssl and https://serverfault.com/questions/607519/wget-ca-directory-etc-ssl-certs-failing-on-ubuntu-14-04 and https://serverfault.com/questions/314635/why-wget-doesnt-verify-ssl-certificates

Comment: and when all normal ways fail and you'll get mad enough, find the stupid library `ldd $(which wget) | grep crypto` and rip it open `strings /your/path/libcrypto.so.1.1 | grep '/.*/' | grep -v '\.c'`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the manpage of `wget`:

> Without this option Wget looks for CA certificates at the system-specified locations, chosen at OpenSSL installation time.

Where's that? [Turns out, that's complicated](https://www.happyassassin.net/2015/01/12/a-note-about-ssltls-trusted-certificate-stores-and-platforms/). It depends on your system, etc.

Simple ways to find out what `wget` actually does are

1. reading its output:

   > Loaded CA certificate '/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt'
2. using `strace`:

   `strace wget https://your-url`

   In the output, you can read which files `wget` opened, tried to open, etc.

Since `strace` produces quite a lot of output, you may want to limit it to certain syscalls. It looks like wget uses `openat` to read files, so:

```
strace -e openat wget https://your-url
```

contains the interesing lines:

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/ca-certificates/trust-source/mozilla.trust.p11-kit", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/ca-certificates/trust-source/anchors/CAcert.org_root.crt", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/ca-certificates/trust-source/anchors/CAcert.org_class3.crt", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt", O_RDONLY) = 3
```

And there are even more locations it looks at, they might even be different for your system.

Answer (score 9):

I had problems with wget not finding my certificates so I installed ca-

```
sudo apt install ca-certificates
```

then I edited:

```
sudo vi /etc/wgetrc
```

and added

```
ca_directory=/etc/ssl/certs
```

or you can just use this command to append it to the end:

> ```
> printf "\nca_directory=/etc/ssl/certs" | sudo tee -a /etc/wgetrc
> ```