# Apache SSL Verify Authority Setup

Tags: apache, ssl

I am confused with SSL certificates on apache. I have the SSL vhost setup in /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf which works fine, but when i try to use wget from another server to pull down some files i get "Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority."

The SSL was bought from cheapsslsecurity.com and the zip comes with multiple CRT files and i'm not sure what is what.

So we have the following files:

```
AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt
COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt
COMODORSADomainValidationecureServerCA.crt
STAR_websitenamehere_com.crt
```

The vhost is currently setup like this:

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/STAR_websitenamehere_com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tld/private/websitenamehere.com.key
SSLCACertificateFile [i have tried all of them here except the STAR_ one and still the same error with wget]
```

The main SSL works in the web browser, but nothing i do seems to allow wget to pull anything without producing an error.

Comment: Seems like it's wget issue. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48949008/wget-where-does-it-look-for-certificates

Comment: It's not just wget issue, it happens on an external system using curl as well, it's something to do with the chain, but i don't fully understand it, or why there are loads of different CRT files